# Why isn't my Empire heater blower working?

Tags: heating

The blower on my empire vented room heater model RH-50-6 will not come on.   We know the motor and fan work and we have replaced the fan control switch.  We don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through the [Owner's manual](http://www.empirezoneheat.com/assets/WMH/Manuals%20May%202013/RH50-65_B-C.pdf)

Have you tried oiling it?

> ### Oiling
>
> The blower motor has an oil hole located on each end of the motor.
> Use #20 motor oil only. It is best to oil the motor several times during
> the heating season using 2 or 3 drops each time. If the motor fails
> to start and hums, it could be a tight bearing due to lack of oil. This
> may be corrected by pouring kerosene in the oil holes, allowing to
> stand for a few hours and then oiling properly

Have you tried cleaning it?

> ### Cleaning
>
> The blower wheel will collect lint and could require cleaning once
> a year. If the air output decreases or the noise level increases, it
> indicates a dirty wheel. Complete removal of the wheel and scrubbing
> it with a brush under flowing water is recommended

Are you waiting long enough?

> ### Fan Control
>
> The automatic fan control is located in the switch box. The switch
> box is attached to the front of the blower assembly. The switch box
> is adjacent to the combustion chamber. The fan control is a nonadjustable
> automatic type. The fan control will require between
> 5 and 10 minutes of main burner operation before the fan control
> “closes” and activates the blower. The blower will continue to run
> between 5 and 10 minutes after the main burner shuts off, before
> the fan control “opens” and deactivates the blower

Have you tried connecting the fan directly to power, to make sure it spins at all?

Comment: It looks like you pasted the exact same text under each of your 3 headings.  Any chance you can edit this to add the correct text?